# xdebug-helper is not being applied to the iframe

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, xdebug

Using xdebug does not trigger on the embeded iframe - while it does on the page containing the iframe.
Same problem happens in Brave browser, while it works in Firefox.

This plugin:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc

Is there a plugin which works, or a setting in Chrome which fixes that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely a limitation of the Chrome/Brave browser. However, you should be able to work around this, by setting [`xdebug.remote_autostart=1`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_autostart) in your php.ini file and restart the web server. With that setting, Xdebug will always (try to) initiate a debugging connection to your IDE.

Comment: Not perfect, but really great solution, could had thought about it myself... 
Will accept this answer, unless I get a solution which also works, where I can't alter remote_autostart.

Comment: I accepted this instead of my own answer, as it seems foolproof - and covers more possible variants I think, like ajax requests from the iframe without having to modify code.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a different solution, which does not require to change php settings.
There is 4 ways to trigger xdebug externally, through GET, POST, cookie and in PHP code `xdebug_break();`.
Since the iframe is loaded through GET, its possible to add a param which enables xdebug.
`https://example.com/iframe.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE`

More information is here: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#activate_debugger

Since one might only want to append xdebug param, when xdebug is enabled in the "main" request - it can be checked with following code:

```php
if (extension_loaded('xdebug') && xdebug_is_enabled()) {
    //add param to url
}
```

Comment: With the same success you can just place `xdebug_break();` into your PHP code and no messing with presentation (HTML/templates) side of things -- a bit cleaner IMO as it's easier to spot and remove.